# why do GeoCoder give timed out?

Tags: android, android-location, google-geocoder, locationlistener, android-gps

I am using geocoder to get the address but I am getting exception all the time 
I have gone through many links in stack over flow but couldnt find any solution

```
addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                    latitude, longitude, 1);
```

this is the exception

```
    java.io.IOException: Timed out waiting for response from server
01-05 17:35:03.915 8708-8708/com.mindtree.vishram W/System.err:     at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(Geocoder.java:136)
01-05 17:35:03.915 8708-8708/com.mindtree.vishram W/System.err:     at com.mindtree.vishram.presenter.FragmentPresenters.OrderMedDeliveryAddressPresenter.getAddressFromGeoCordinates(OrderMedDeliveryAddressPresenter.java:90)
01-05 17:35:03.915 8708-8708/com.mindtree.vishram W/System.err:     at com.mindtree.vishram.presenter.FragmentPresenters.OrderMedDeliveryAddressPresenter.getGeoCordinates(OrderMedDeliveryAddressPresenter.java:76)
01-05 17:35:03.916 8708-8708/com.mindtree.vishram W/System.err:     at com.mindtree.vishram.presenter.FragmentPresenters.OrderMedDeliveryAddressPresenter.currentLocationImageViewClick(OrderMedDeliveryAddressPresenter.java:42)
01-05 17:35:03.916 8708-8708/com.mindtree.vishram W/System.err:     at com.mindtree.vishram.view.FragmentViews.OrderMedicineDeliveryAddressfrag$1.onClick(OrderMedicineDeliveryAddressfrag.java:67)
01-05 17:35:03.917 8708-8708/com.mindtree.vishram W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
01-05 17:35:03.917 8708-8708/com.mindtree.vishram W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
01-05 17:35:03.917 8708-8708/com.mindtree.vishram W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
01-05 17:35:03.917 8708-8708/com.mindtree.vishram W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-05 17:35:03.918 8708-8708/com.mindtree.vishram W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
01-05 17:35:03.918 8708-8708/com.mindtree.vishram W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
01-05 17:35:03.918 8708-8708/com.mindtree.vishram W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-05 17:35:03.918 8708-8708/com.mindtree.vishram W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
01-05 17:35:03.918 8708-8708/com.mindtree.vishram W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: my guess is either: something with the Activity need to be AppCompatActivity, or you do a lengthy operation duraing critical time, or you execute this in a separate thread in a stage where you should not

Comment: its working fine when its through data network @Hanan